# AngularJS - promises and error handling

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

I'm trying to find out an answer to my question - does

```
myFunction()
        .then(function (response) { })
         .catch(function(error) { });
```

is the same as

```
myFunction()
        .then(function (response) { },
        function(error) {});
```

to handle errors from the promise? If so which one should be used as best practice?

Comment: The default promise type for angular is $q and per the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q the two are the same.  However, this is only for promises generated from angular.  There are other promise libraries out there.

Comment: @losSteveos can you provide some useful examples?

Comment: I use first one, I find it much nicer and cleaner to read.

Comment: The industry is the process of changing out promisses. It's actually been added to the spec in es6.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise is a basic intro, https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises talks about poly-fills because not all browsers support native promise yet.

Comment: For additional libraries out there I suggest doing a search on https://www.npmjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with they both you will get the same result.

From [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service

> `catch(errorCallback)` – shorthand for `promise.then(null, errorCallback)`

About to which one to use as a best practice... It's a matter of perspective: IMHO, you can use them both indistinctly.